# .isPlaying errors with Pause/Play Button in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm having a problem using .isplaying in swiftui. I have an error everytime with a button I created to control a pause/play feature. Basically, the button should play the song if nothing is playing and stop whatever is playing if something was playing previously. I am not sure what this error may stem from and if more code should be posted I can do that no problem.

Here is the code and the error.

```
Button(action:  {

                            let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "vcem983", ofType: "mp3")

                            if self.audioPlayer!.isPlaying == true  {

                                self.audioPlayer!.pause()

                                self.audioPlayer! = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound!))
                                self.audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
                                self.audioPlayer!.play()

                            }   else    {

                                self.audioPlayer!.play()

                            }

                            // Continuously fetching current audio time
                            // Used background to avoid affecting main thread
                            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async   {

                                while true  {

                                    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20
                                    let currenttime = self.audioPlayer!.currentTime / self.audioPlayer!.duration
                                    let timeForLabel = CGFloat(currenttime) * screenWidth
                                    self.time = timeForLabel
                                    print(currenttime)
                                }
                            }
                        })  {
                            Image(systemName: "waveform")
                                .font(.caption)
                            Text("EMOTION 98.3")
                                .font(.caption)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            }
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 300)
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                                .cornerRadius(35)
```

[image: Code + error]

Comment: There are a few things you need to check. Is `self.audioPlayer` not equal to `nil`? If so, then make sure also that `sound` doesn't equal `nil`. You can check these things by setting breakpoints within your code and checking the values of these variables.

Comment: The reason of crash is force-unwrap for optional `self.audioPlayer!`.. please show the code where you manage `self.audioPlayer` property... create and/or modify.

Comment: Thanks. I don’t really understand what a “force unwrap” is. When you say show code where self.audioPlayer is managed, does that mean a separate swift file? If so, then I do not have one and that may be my problem. What is the best way to manage self.audioPlayer?

Answer (score 1):

You use force unwrapping - it leads to crash. Try use my code and you can update logic. Unfortunately, there is no state `viewDidLoad()` in swiftUI and I moved initialization of `audioPlayer` to `onAppear`.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {

            if self.audioPlayer.isPlaying {
                self.audioPlayer.pause()
            } else {
                self.audioPlayer.play()
            }

            // Continuously fetching current audio time
            // Used background to avoid affecting main thread
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async   {
                while true  {
                    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20
                    let currenttime = self.audioPlayer.currentTime / self.audioPlayer.duration
                    let timeForLabel = CGFloat(currenttime) * screenWidth
                    print(currenttime)
                }
            }
        })  {
            Image(systemName: "waveform")
                .font(.caption)
            Text("EMOTION 98.3")
                .font(.caption)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }.onAppear {
            guard let sound = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "vcem983", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }
            do {
                self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: sound)
                self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            } catch let parseError {
                print("error parse: \(parseError)")
            }
        }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 300)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                .cornerRadius(35)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! This did kill the error when the button was pressed, but I actually have multiple buttons that play different audio sounds. When I did the .onAppear on the other buttons it won’t play those audio sounds. Only the one sound file plays.